# Android design game card UI

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I need help with the design of my card game.

1. I having a Vector of cards (player cards), each item appers in ImageView (Already done and working).

   ```
   private Vector<Card> myCards;
   ```
2. I having a LinearLayout that holding 5 imageView's.

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/myCardsLayout"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:paddingBottom="10dip">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/my_card_1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
       />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/my_card_2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
         />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/my_card_3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
        />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/my_card_4"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
       />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/my_card_5"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
      />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. I want to choose the cards that i want to drop by click on the card, And that the player will see this by jumping the card slightly up (or another recommended way).

I will implement that on android:onClick function (goToMainMenu is a temporary statement).

Any idea ? Thanks!

**UPDATE1**

```
  public void myCard1OnClick(View view) {
    view.setSelected(true);
    if(view.isSelected()) {
        int y = view.getTop();
        view.setTop(y - 30);
    }
    else{
        int y = view.getTop();
        view.setTop(y + 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you need to set onclick listener to imageView, which will add bottom margin to the ImageView. That is one of ways you can do it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko - Please take a look at my update, the card is moving up and back down immediately after

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I've suggested to increase margin of the view. I don't know how to fix it, since it is not my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an onclick function on cards that moves and give them a function that takes their x and y cordinates and then you just inflate y to move up.

Comment: I tried, But the card is moving up and back down immediatly after. Look on my update at the main post.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `setX()` and `setY()` view properties to move across a space.
And about the issue of moving the card and after that it get back to its original position, maybe its because the set selected its not working, and then enters to the else statement.